# What data structure should I use to store a collection of .fasta headers?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, bioinformatics

I'm trying to write a perl program that will split up a fasta header:

```
gi|4140243|dbj|AB022087.1|_Xenopus_laevis_mRNA_for_cytochrome_P450,_complete_cds,_clone_MC1
```

Into it's `|` seperated parts:

```
gi
4140243
dbj
AB022087.1
_Xenopus_laevis_mRNA_for_cytochrome_P450,_complete_cds,_clone_MC1
```

I can do this using `split`:

```
my @hits = split(/\|/, $hits);

my ($gi, $number, $gb, $id, $name);
foreach (@hits) {
  $gi.= "$hits[0]\n";
  $number .= "$hits[1]\n";
  $gb .= "$hits[2]\n";
  $id .= "$hits[3]\n";
  $name .= "$hits[4]\n";
}

my @gi = split('\n', $gi);
my @number = split('\n', $number);
my @gb = split('\n', $gb);
my @id = split('\n', $id);
my @name = split('\n', $name);
```

Now each part of each header (contained in `$hits`) is an element in an individual array. What I want to do next is print back each element of each array so that I can produce a list of element[0] for each array, element[1] for each array...

I'm unsure as to whether this will require a hash of hashes or array of arrays.

I'm fairly new to perl so any suggestions would be greatly helpful.

I'm also aware that the above might not be the slickest way of achieving what I want - again any comments would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Does $hits contain one header or many? If it's only one, so to split it into variables you can do something like:

```
my ($gi, $number, $gb, $id, $name) = split(/\|/, $hits);
```

And each variable will contain corresponding value.

If $hits contains multiple headers then firstly just split lines and after that split each header in loop. Here is an example and result will be array of hashes:

```
my @hits = split(/\n/, $hits);
my @result;
for my hit ( @hits ) {
    my ($gi, $number, $gb, $id, $name) = split(/\|/, $hits);
    push(@result, {
        gi => $gi,
        number => $number,
        gb => $gb,
        id => $id,
        name => $name,
    });
}
```

Of course the example does not include any error check (such as - does header string really matches the format or not?), but you should include them in a real application if they are needed.

PS: I think you really have to start with [that](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html)

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer. $hits contains multiple headers separated by \n

Comment: OK great - I'll have a play around with that. Thanks for the helpful link too!

Comment: I'm confused as how you've created a hash without first declaring it? Don't I need to declare my %results before I can access  $results{go}

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, arrays are for homogeneous data ("a bunch of things"), while hashes are for heterogeneous data ("a name, a number, and a birthday").  If your data splits naturally into a bunch of internally-heterogeneous things ("a bunch of personal information records, each of which has a name, a number, and a birthday"), the natural data structure is an array of hashrefs (see note#1).

In your case, `$hits` is a list of headers.  So we'll make an array, call it `@headers`, each element of which is an individual header represented as a hashref.  We can turn a delimited string into a list with `split`, and we can turn one kind of list into another with `map`:

```
my @headers = map {
    make_header_hashref($_)
} split(/\n/, $hits);

sub make_header_hashref {
    my ($header_string) = @_;
    my ($gi, $number, $gb, $id, $name) = split(/\|/, $header_string);

    return {
        gi      => $gi,
        number  => $number,
        gb      => $gb,
        id      => $id,
        name    => $name,
    };
}
```

(I split the conversion of header string to header hashref into a sub because
(a) that's what you'd do in real code and (b) it clarifies the structure of
the `map`.)

You now have an array of hashrefs, so you can iterate through them and
otherwise deal with the headers as units rather than as collections of
attributes.

note#1:  Well, really we would want an object describing the association, implemented as an array of objects that represent the records.